# answer file for chef installs Opsworks

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I have an install for Linux that requires a few answers beyond yes and no. One is directory location ( which has a default) and accept for the EULA, the rest are yes and no answers.

I have a script in a recipe that runs bash, and I get to a certain point and it hangs, looking for input is my guess.

The important part is

```
echo "/opt/mydir"  # directory location
echo "yes" \n      # confirm directory location
sleep 10           # added a pause while it did its thing. Needed?    
echo "yes" \n      # another question asked
sleep 10           #another pause
echo "accept" \n   # EULA agreement, requires accept or decline
echo "y" \n        # another question asked
sleep 10           # another pause
echo "y" \n        #another question asked
sleep 10           # another pause before the next command is sent that runs another stage of the install.
```

According to the logfile, it is hanging at the EULA agreement, which makes me believe that it is waiting on accept. If I run it manually it will prompt for accept or decline with every input unless it sees accept or decline.

So what can I do different to make this work?  I searched a few days looking for an answer and have not found any as it is not a simple yes or no script.

Comment: Please show your recipe code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally stumbled on it from a coworker.  Even simpler than I thought.

```
script 'Install Software' do
interpreter "bash"
cwd "/opt/fidir"
code <<-EOH
cp /home/user/installs/fidir/Install/oskey.lic /opt/fidir/insttemp/oskey.lic
/opt/fidir/fast psx <<-EOFFIDIR02
y
n
AEC
02
n
/var/fidir
1
n
EOFFIDIR02
EOH
```

end